# Is there any online/software tool available to select/find/narrow down a research topic?

Tags: web-apps, desktop-environment

Is there any online/software tool available to select/find/narrow down a research topic for 'Impact' research journal article/PhD thesis/Masters thesis?

There are some tools available like [this one](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dec/essay.topic.generator.html).

It should run on Web-browser or windows desktop. Must be free. And, more versatile.